# Angular - How to fix "ERROR TS2322: Type 'ModuleWithProviders<any>' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any>'"

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a webapp using Angular, but at the time of compilation I get this error which I can't solve:

> ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(22,5): error TS2322: Type
>   'ModuleWithProviders' is not assignable to type 'any[] |
>   Type'.   Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is missing the following
>   properties from type 'Type': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 5
>   more.

That's my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot()
  ],
  imports: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The error is reported on the line: **ToastrModule.forRoot()**

And that's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "pum-pum-pum",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As i see, you have added Modules under declarations and components under imports, you should add Modules under imports and components under declarations.

Comment: Could you please add a reference to official docs?

Answer (score 6):

1. `declarations` is save `components`,`pipes` or `directives`.
2. `imports` is save `modules`.

```
@NgModule({
  // right
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot()
  ],
  // right
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all this in import not in @NgModule({declarations:
FormsModule,
HttpClientModule,
ComponentsModule,
RouterModule,
AppRoutingModule,
NgbModule,
ToastrModule.forRoot()
any module or importation is not added in declarations.

this will be like -
imports: [
BrowserAnimationsModule,
FormsModule,
HttpClientModule,
ComponentsModule,
RouterModule,
AppRoutingModule,
NgbModule,
ToastrModule.forRoot()
],

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).